# How to change date format using PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have input string: `'10/22'` where 10 is a number of month and 22 is a number of year. I need to convert it to `dd-mm-yyyy` date. So I wrote a script to do it:

```
<?php

$date = '10/22'; // m-y date
$date = '01/' . $date; // Gets d-m-y date (01/10/22)

$base_year = 2000;
$date_parts = explode('/', $date);
$date_parts[2] = strval(intval($date_parts[2]) + $base_year); // Gets 4 digits year (2022)
$date = implode('/', $date_parts); // Joins array elements with a string
$new_date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);

$dmy = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $new_date)->format('d-m-Y'); // Creates date with specified format

echo $dmy; // Will display 01-10-2022, this is what I need
```

But I am afraid that this way is too bad and I need help to make this script more optimal, if such way exists. Any tips?

Comment: Is the output for 01/98 meant to be 01-01-2098?

Comment: @Phil yes it is

Comment: Based on this example, the minimum year is `2000` and maximum is `2099` - is that correct or is there a different maximum?

Answer (score 1):

You can complete this in just 2 lines with exploding the current date on `/` and then imploding them later on with an `array_merge` like below:

```
<?php

$date = '10/22'; // m-y date

function getFormattedDate($date){
    list($month,$year) = explode("/", $date);
    return implode("-",array_merge(["01"], [$month],["20". $year]));
}

echo getFormattedDate($date);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/51049)

Comment: What is advantage of using list?

Comment: @WideWood It simplye creates those 2 variables and injects the values respectively received from explode function. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php 
I used it here for clean and readable code.

Comment: You can use list when a function returns an array, or you could use it on an array directly. list( $a, $b ) = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]; $a will be 1, $b will be 2. Its the same as $arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]; $a = $arr[0]; $b = $arr[1];

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

`echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', '01/'.$date)->format('d-m-Y');`

Output : https://3v4l.org/9kb5g

Comment: What is difference between / and - in date formats? What's better?

Comment: This is nice but it returns `0022` for year though.

Comment: @WideWood  This will work for you: https://3v4l.org/9kb5g

Comment: Jacob Mulquin  I have modified your answer. Hope it's ok to you